# Regex which doesn't allow accents

Tags: bash, shell

have a shell script. I want to define a regex that doesn't allow accents

I already defined my regex like this:

```
regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

I expected it to not allow strings like Léo but it still does.

Edit:

I use my regex as a parameter in my loop

```
  while [[ "$name" =~ $regex ]]
```

Comment: Where do you use that regex? With grep?

Comment: No, it's a parameter in my loop while [[ "$name" =~ $regex ]]

Comment: "*Ranges are very collating-sequence-dependent, and portable programs should avoid relying on them.*"

Comment: Is that your real assignment? You can't have spaces around `=`.

Comment: Try setting `LC_COLLATE=POSIX`. Does that change things?

Comment: @BenjaminW. sorry, it's not the real assignement. I edited

Comment: @melpomene How do you use it? I juste declare `LC_COLLATE=POSIX` and erase regex?

Comment: [Live example](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyg1PbXCVj0uOlG3ylE3ykDXMlZbRZ2LKy8xN9VW3efwynwgx8c53tnfx8cxxNU2wD/YM4KLKzNNITpaQUkFpExJwbZOQQVskEJsrLVCSUZqHpeCQmpyRr5CZWoxV2pOcSqMn5fPlZb5/z8A)

Comment: @melpomene Wow! Thanks! It works!

Comment: You could also use `LC_ALL=C` and `[[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing a solution with the different comments:

Once you have set the locale to `POSIX` or `C`, the `[:alnum:]` alphanumeric characters class only comprise the ASCII characters that excludes diacritics.

Other more evolved RegEx engines may have special flags for diacritics, but not the POSIX Extended RegEx POSIX ERE that is dealt with Bash.

```
regex="^[[:alnum:]]+$"
```

```
while LC_ALL=POSIX && [[ "$name" =~ $regex ]]; do
  unset LC_ALL # restore LC_ALL to its value before the RegEx test
  # do stuffs in the loop
done
```

Comment: 1) `[[ LC_ALL=POSIX && $NAME =~ $regex ]]` will not work. The first `LC_ALL=POSIX` is not an assignment, it tests if the string `LC_ALL=POSIX` has nonzero length. It is the case from [bash conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) `-n string` `string` `True if the length of string is non-zero.`. It will be always true. Then `"$name" =~ $regex` is checked with LC_ALL unchanged. 2) `unset LC_ALL` unsets the variable, it doesn't restores it's previous value.